# PHP Ignore mysql deprecated errors

Tags: php

I'm using a web app based on an older PHP so it uses mysql* functions that throws a deprecated function errors all the time and wont let me see the page. This has been asked many times but all the answers were "switch to mysqli/pdo" and "you should not use these functions anymore". Those answers are not really helping me since the app is huge and changing all the mysql functions to mysqli is completely out of the question. Also many of projects I'm working on are based on it.

I would like to ask for a solution that will help me bypass this problem without need to rewrite the whole app and all the projects that use it. On Windows I simply downgraded to php 5.4 but now I transfered to Ubuntu 14.04 and this doesn't seem to be possible in here. Is there any way I can configure PHP to perhaps not show these errors (yes I'm well aware that would not show all the deprecated errors in general).

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

Comment: setting error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED in php.ini made no difference for me.

Comment: Don't ignore it, fix it! It's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: I understand it should be fixed but its our company app for ecommerce and projects based on it will just keep coming and I can't imagine rewriting all these functions on every project I get to work on especially when clients will expect just little things to be developed in there. That would take hours just to rewrite the whole thing and when they would expect project to be done I would just start coding it.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: yeah! because you're lazy to upgrade to PDO/MySQLi

Comment: Just want to say the whole app contains about 5000 files (without images) and is mvc. I may be lazy but somehow I still can't imagine anybody rewriting all the functions in there and then on all the other projects based on it.

Comment: With money everything is possible!